# Does proximity of moment generating functions implies proximity of characteristic functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions, moment-generating-functions

Let's assume that $U$ and $V$ are non-negative random variables.     Suppose that
\begin{align}
 \sup_{t \ge 0 } \frac{| M_U(-t) - M_V(-t)|}{t} \le \epsilon 
\end{align}
where $M_U(t)$ and $M_V(t)$ are moment generating functions.

A few facts:

1. Technically $M(-t)$ is known as Laplace transform.
2. $M(t)$ unique on an open interval. Therefore, this question is well defined.
3. $ t \to M(-t)$ is decreasing.

**Question:** Does this imply that
\begin{align}
 \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R} } \frac{| \phi_U(t) - \phi_V(t)| }{|t|}\le f(\epsilon) 
\end{align}
where $\phi_U(t)$ and  $\phi_V(t)$ are characteristic functions, and $f$ is some function that goes to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$.

I was thinking of using that $\phi(t)=M(it)$, but this doesn't work out.

Comment: Is your first condition ever true for $U\neq V$? It can't be in the case of $U, V$ both discrete positive.

Comment: @PepeSilvia  Thanks. I modified the answer to fix this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for normalizing by $t$ (as opposed to just looking at maximum distance between the functions)? (Probablly one obvious reason I'm missing)

Comment: @ClementC.   This type of expression shows up when you try control Levy distance with characteristic functions.  I would be fine with a result for just a maximum distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $U_n=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{n+1}$, $V_n=\delta_{n}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\vert M_{U_n}(-t)-M_{V_n}(-t)\vert}{t}=\frac{\vert \frac{e^{-(n+1)t}}{2}+\frac{e^{-(n-1)t}}{2}-e^{-nt}\vert}{t}=\frac{e^{-(n-1)t}}{2}\frac{(1-e^{-t})^2}{t}. 
\end{align*}
Say there are an infinite sequence of $\{t_{n_k}\}_k$ and an $\epsilon>0$ such that \begin{align*}
\frac{e^{-(n_k-1)t_{n_k}}}{2}\frac{(1-e^{-t_{n_k}})^2}{t_{n_k}}>\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Then we must have $t_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. But
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{-(n_k-1)t_{n_k}}}{2}\frac{(1-e^{-t_{n_k}})^2}{t_{n_k}}\leq\frac{1}{2}\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-t_{n_k}})^2}{t_{n_k}}=0
\end{align*}
by a simple application of L'Hopital's Rule.

However,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\vert \phi_{U_n}(t)-\phi_{V_n}(t)\vert}{\vert t \vert}&=\frac{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\cos((n-1)t)}{2}+\frac{\cos((n+1)t)}{2}-\cos(nt)\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sin((n-1)t)}{2}+\frac{\sin((n+1)t)}{2}-\sin(nt)\right)^2}}{\vert t\vert} \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}
\end{align*}
when $t=\pi$. So for any $\epsilon,f$ I have a pair $U_n,V_n$ that satisfy your MGF constraint but not your CF constraint.

Comment: I think your conjecture may be true in the case where your random variables are uniformly restricted to a bounded interval rather than simply being non-negative.

Comment: Thanks. So $U_n$ converges to $V_n$ in moment generating function, but not in the characteristic function?  Is this right?

Comment: I wouldn't use those exact words, that one sequence converges to another. But in principle I see what you're saying, and yes, in the case of $U_n,V_n$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$ your MGF supremum goes to 0 but you CF supremum doesn't.

Comment: This is very interesting. I didn't expect this.  I always treated the MGF and CF as having very similar properties. What about the other way around? Can we control MGF's with CF's? This is probably for another question.

Comment: They're often similar-looking algebraically, take for example the Normal or Exponential distributions. But take a discrete distribution and you'll see that you're taking a weighted average of trig functions (for CF) instead of exponentials (for MGF). There are lots of effects to this. First, $|\phi(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t$. Second, see what happens if $\mathbb{P}[X=x]=a>0$ and you change $x$. Make $x$ large positive and you affect $M_X(t)$ a lot for $t>0$ but very little for $t<0$. For $\phi_X$ you're adding an oscillation of period proportional to $\frac{1}{x}$ in the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: One thing worth knowing is that for random variables $\{X_n\}_n$, $X$ with MGFs $\{M_{X_n}\}_n, M_X$, if $M_{X_n}(t)\rightarrow M_{X}(t)$ for $t$ in an open interval then $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution, which means that their characteristic functions converge everywhere. Conversely, if $\phi_{X_n}(t)\rightarrow \phi_{X}(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (\*) then the distribution converge, so the MGFs converge on the interior of where $M_X$ is continuous. I think you can make the statement ending at (\*) sharper but I'd need to find some papers I read a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks.  This all sounds very interesting...